# Androidアプリでスクロール時にViewを追随させるには

Tags: android

Androidアプリ開発で困っています。
フローティングしてスクロール時についてくるViewの実装方法を教えて下さい。

イメージは以下サンプルの「asideFixedBox」のような動きになるViewです。
http://detelu.com/blog/sample/jQuery/floatbox/index2.html

常時固定位置ではなく、あくまである一定以上スクロールしたらついてくるという仕様です。
標準・ライブラリ問わず簡単に実現出来る方法を探しています。

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

こんなのでしょうか。

この手のライブラリはandroid sticky viewとかで検索すると色々ヒットします

Comment: まさに探していたものでした。ありがとうございました